# Linear Algebra - orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

can someone help me understand this?

[image]

https://gyazo.com/d828940ff01bd1daf1f4cd6b437d9529

$A_2$, $R_2$, $R_3$ are $3\times 1$ vectors and $d$ and $e$ are constants. $R_2$ and $R_3$ are orthogonal with length one.

Comment: Perhaps someone with the gift of divination, mind reading or something like that: the link you gave is lacking lines, so you better find them and write down the whole thing here. You can use http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Vector of length one is a vector with length equal to one, e.g. in 2D $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ or $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$. Orthogonal vectors are vectors that are perpendicular, e.g. in 2D $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. See for more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality

Answer (score 2):

Orthogonal means $R_2 \cdot R_3 = 0$, length one means $R_2 \cdot R_2 = 1$ etc., the dot means the scalar product. Note that we can write the standard scalar product also as matrix products:
$$
a \cdot b = b \cdot a = a^T b = b^T a
$$
(in case of column vectors).

So
$$
A_2^T R_3 
= A_2 \cdot R_3 
= (d R_2 + e R_3) \cdot R_3
= d R_2 \cdot R_3 + e R_3 \cdot R_3
= d \cdot 0 + e \cdot 1 
= e
$$
similar
$$
A_2^T R_2 
= A_2 \cdot R_2 
= (d R_2 + e R_3) \cdot R_2
= d R_2 \cdot R_2 + e R_3 \cdot R_2
= d \cdot 1 + e \cdot 0 
= d
$$

Comment: Thank you! I was confused by the transpose and didn't realize that $A_2^{T}R_3 = A_2*R_3$. Makes sense now